# .NET syntax for calling constructor in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell

Using the [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace, [PrincipalContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class in PowerShell. I am unable to call `PrincipalContext Constructor (ContextType, String)` via

```
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::PrincipalContext($ContextType, $ContextName)
```

I get error `"Method invocation failed because [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext] does not contain a method named 'PrincipalContext'.`"

Can it only be called the following way?

```
New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ContextType, $ContextName
```

Would like to understand why it works the second way but not the first way. Is there a way to do this with square brackets?

Full code is this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
$ContextName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$ContextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Machine
$PrincipalContext = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::PrincipalContext($ContextType, $ContextName)
$IdentityType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType]::SamAccountName
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($PrincipalContext, $IdentityType, 'Administrators')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the double colon after a .net class is used to call a static method on that class.

See: [Using Static Classes and Methods](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347632.aspx)

Using the below syntax:

```
[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::PrincipalContext($ContextType, $ContextName)
```

You are trying to call a *static* method named PrincipalContext on the PrincipalContext class instead of the constructor.

> Can it only be called the following way?

AFAIK, you need to create the instance of the class (call the constructor) using the New-Object cmdlet.

> Would like to understand why it works the second way but not the first way. Is there a way to do this with square brackets?

It works the second way because you are correctly creating a new object and calling the constructor. It doesn't work the first way because you are not calling the constructor - you are attempting to call a static method.

Comment: Please dumb it down. I don't really know what that should mean to me in this context.

Comment: @Entbark - I expanded my original answer.

Comment: For those finding this, in Powershell v5.1 (maybe even 5.0 - but not before) classes have the constructors available from the square brackets notation.This alows Powershell ISE to use Intellisense for the constructor signatures. Called like so: `[System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new($ContextType, $ContextName)`.