# Making .NET array type in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i'm trying to make `System.Memory[char]` .

`[System.Memory[char]]::Memory([char],0,10)` [*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29900546/12669337) says it can't find System.Memory type .

Also tried [*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448836/12669337)

```
[System.Memory`3+[[char],0,10]]@()
```

Solution: The issue seems to be the .NET version used by the Powershell .

Comment: As an aside re `\`<n>` in PowerShell type literals, such as ``[System.Memory`1]`` (represented in C# as `System.Memory<T>`): `<n>` refers to the number of _type parameters_ in _generic .NET types_. Thus, [``[System.Memory`1]``](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1) implies _one_ type parameter, which is correctly supplied as `[char]` in your first attempt: `[System.Memory[char]]` (which you could also express as ``[System.Memory`1[char]]``, but that is only necessary for accessing _nested_ types; see link). `<n>` is unrelated to the _number of constructor arguments_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the **static *pseudo* method `::new()`**, introduced in PowerShell v5, that **provides access to a type's *constructors***.<sup>[1]</sup>

```sh
# Initialize a [System.Memory[char]] instance with 10 NUL (0x0) chars,
# from a [char[]] array.
[System.Memory[char]]::new(
  [char[]]::new(10)
)
```

Note: The two [`` System.Memory`1 `` constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1.-ctor) both require a `[char[]]` array as an argument. The two additional arguments in the 3-parameter overload, `start` and `length`, must refer to a range of elements *within that array*.

The above simply creates a 10-element array to begin with (implicitly using `NUL` characters), obviating the need for the additional arguments.

If you wanted the input array to use a given character other than `NUL`, you could use something like `, [char] 'x' * 10`:
`, [char] 'x'` create a single-element array with char. `'x'`, which `* 10` then replicates to return a 10-element array. Note that the array will be `[object[]]`-typed, not `[char[]]`-typed, but it still works.

---

Note:

- `[System.Memory[char]]@()` does *not* work, because in order for PowerShell to translate this cast to a single-parameter constructor call, the operand must be a `[char[]]` array:

  - `[System.Memory[char]] [char[]] @()`
- Fundamentally, the **[`` System.Memory`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memory-1) type is available only in .NET *Core* 2.1+ / .NET 5+**.

  - The simplest way to check if the type is available in your PowerShell session is if `[bool] $IsCoreClr` returns `$true` - in other words: **you need to be running [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, the  modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition of PowerShell.

---

<sup>[1] In earlier PowerShell versions you need to use the **[`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) cmdlet**, which uses [argument(-parsing) mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), as all cmdlets do. As such, its syntax doesn't map cleanly onto the [expression-mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#expression-mode) syntax that is familiar from method/constructor calls, especially with respect to passing a *single* argument that is an *array*, as in this case:

`New-Object System.Memory[char] -ArgumentList (, (New-Object char[] 10))`

Note the need to wrap the array constructed by `, [char] 0) * 10` in *another* array, namely a transitory one that is needed to make `New-Object` treat the original array as a *single* argument for the target constructor.

Additionally, `::new()` performs better, though that will often not matter. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68022186/45375) for details.</sup>

Comment: i did try that too, says can't find System.Memory type

Comment: @irvnriir, please see my update. There is indeed no `System.Memory` type, but there is `System.Memory\`1`, aka `System.Memory<T>`

Comment: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetSystemVersion()` outputs v4[..] , this is the reason ? isn't Windows Powershell always running on the .NET Framework 4.[..] ?

Comment: @irvnriir, this method seems to return a value that is frozen in time for backward compatibility. Use the following instead to see the true framework version: `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`. Yes, Windows PowerShell runs on the legacy, Windows-only .NET Framework, whose latest and _last_ version is v4.8.x

Comment: the command doesn't work in this Powershell, tried also with `write-host` and `write-output` .

Comment: is said that it works on OSx . command for Win P -- [ink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829654/12669337) .

Comment: @irvnriir, [`[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription) works in .NET Framework v4.7.1 and above, and therefore also on Windows. (and in .NET (Core) v1 and above).

Comment: @irvnriir, I've updated the answer with the following: The simplest way to check if the type is available in your PowerShell session is if `[bool] $IsCoreClr` returns `$true` - in other words: **you need to be running [_PowerShell (Core) 7+_](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, the  modern, cross-platform, install-on-demand edition of PowerShell.

Comment: the article you've linked is wrong, since i have 4.8 .

Comment: @irvnriir, the premise of your question is that you want to use the `System.Memory\`1` type. My answer and its links are telling you that you need .NET _Core_ 2.1 or higher to use this type, and therefore PowerShell _Core_. What is wrong is your attempt to use the type from .NET _Framework_ 4.8, which implies the legacy _Windows PowerShell_ edition.

Comment: @mclement0 ... i mean `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription`

Comment: @irvnriir, the previously linked docs state that this property is available in "4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8" (as well as in .NET _Core_ since v1), and it works in my v4.8-based Windows PowerShell sessions. Does it not work for you?